# Inserting Data Into Mysql Database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

im having the following code:

```
private void setCounter(String counter,String stName){


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("XXX");


        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vCounter",counter));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StName",stName));

           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }


class setCountertoDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {//kept


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            setCounter(StringCounter,streetName);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

PHP file:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not Connect:'. mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("a6241050_Stpeeds",$con);


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO DBNAME (vCounter) VALUES('".$_REQUEST['vCounter']."') WHERE StName='".$_REQUEST['StName']."'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the application is running well and there's no error in the logcat, but when i check the database there's no data inserted, please help with that, knowing that i used almost the same code to select values from database and it worked, but it's not working with the insert !

Comment: As you can read in the [docu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/insert.html), MySQL doesn't allow `WHERE` in an `INSERT` - what are you trying to do with that anyway? (You'd have known if you had an error check like `mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());`)

Comment: @kingkero thanks alot, yea the where is not allowed in insert, sorry for that, i'll just try to use the update instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hI if you have to make a new entry can not use the WHERE:

```
  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO DBNAME (vCounter) VALUES('".$_REQUEST['vCounter']."'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE table_name SET vcounter='".$_REQUEST['vcounter']."'WHERE StName='".$_REQUEST['StName']."'");
```

This should do the job.

Comment: i just did so and it's work out like a charm :), thank alot :)

Comment: @Izzo32 happy to know that I could help.